# AirPort - How to put accessories on a network using command line instead of AirPort App

Tags: network, wifi, command-line, airport

I have an application where my application device starts a WAC(Wi-Fi Accessory Configuration). I then use either my Mac or iPhone to put that application device on a network.

In Mac, I see my application device accessory if I click on my WiFi under "New Accessory" or if I simply open AirPort Utility in which case it shows under "Other Wi-Fi Devices". I then click on my application device accessory and put it on the desired network.

In iPhone, In WiFi - I see my application device accessory at the bottom under "SET UP NEW DEVICE.." when I click on it, I am able to put the device on the network I want.

Now, I want to do this using Command Line(CLI). I've already made a link to airport and I have Airport working on command line. If I run the scan command (*airport -s*) I can see my device showing up as a "Unconfigured Device".

However, I'm not sure how to put my device on the network using command line. I couldn't find anything related to it. Any help on this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) The question as it is written is a bit hard to understand. Kindly consider editing it to make it clear to get quick and helpful answers.

Comment: @unknowndomain Hi, is it clearer?

Comment: So you are looking to configure Apple AirPort products via a command line interface.

Comment: @unknowndomain Yes.

Comment: Basically as far as I am aware the answer is no, and Apple has discontinued the entire product lineup so this is unlikely to change.